# Ferrite Choke wiring, understanding the datasheet and how it affects the signal

Tags: inductor, ferrite-bead, winding

I've been tasked with digitising an old analogue product for my company. I'm attempting to reverse engineer the analogue circuitry with no documentation (it was designed by an outside consultancy 30 years ago, the company only has gerber files). My experience is mostly embedded programming/digital systems so I'm by no means an analogue expert.

The circuit produces a high power square pulse to an antenna (coil of wire with a handful of turns), but the transmit circuitry and the antenna and the antenna and the ground are separated by a ferrite choke. I've been told that the product failed some kind of certification back in the day, possibly EMI testing and adding the choke allowed it to pass. Now I can observe that with the choke replaced with a short circuit that the signal is indeed much noiser, so the choke helps to attenuate background noise. The other issue however, is that the shape of the waveform transmitted to the antenna looks different.

This is not an exact comparison but the shapes are extremely similar, if the magnitudes were the same. Purple is with the choke (expected) and blue is without the choke. The purple looks "more square" and it looks like maybe the RLC that is added with the choke was taken into account with the design?

[image]

The ferrite core:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/laird-signal-integrity-products/28B0625-100/240-2115-ND/571923

How its wired:
[image]
My questions:

- What type of choke is this?
- Why is it wired this way?
- Is it possible to find a surface mount equivalent?
- What can I look at to research this problem, e.g. keywords for google?
- Although the choke reduces background noise it also enhances the signal to the coil, any broad guesses as to why this may be or experiments that I can try?

Any help with any of this would be appreciated.
Thanks

**As an addendum**, there are three wires: 1 goes to the transmitter, 1 goes to the receiver, 1 goes to the grounds that the anntennas share. Both antennas are separated from the circuit through this choke. The schematic shows the choke "FILT-B" twice but it is just indicating a connection from the same choke.

Transmit circuit, receives pulses from a 555 timer to a voltage shifter to a push-pull to a FET for power switching. Labels 5 and 6 go to the transmitter, all other connections are open circuit

[image]

Receive circuit, second antenna connection is labelled 4. There is some damping configuration and clipping diodes. It then goes to an op amp for filtering and amplification purposes.

[image]

Comment: A schematic is needed - I don't mean it would be helpful either; it is needed, mandatory for decent help to be offered.

Comment: I agree, I can't post the schematic in its entirety but I'll attempt to post the relevant transmit and receive circuitry

Answer (score 0):

This choke is part of an LC harmonic antenna resonant transmitter. With some effort characterizing the antenna, it can be improved but not with insufficient details on cable balun, Z antenna, and increasing resonant current while raising impedance and current to bandstop filter.  this is similar to blocking Class E PWM except inverted where you want the antenna resonant current to be radiated instead of blocked.

No answer given yet until desired output specs are given.

Comment: I appreciate the response and you've given me some terms to google - I won't pretend to yet understand what you're referring to. In regards to desired output specs; what are you requesting? Could you please explain a little bit more in detail what I can provide.

Comment: Just to add my comment, the antenna coils are hand wound and are approximately 200uH @ 10KHz with a resistance of  2-3 ohms

Comment: Is this for wireless power transfer WPT?

Comment: This is for a Pulse Induction Metal Detector. The transmit antenna radiates over an area, the receive antenna picks up the radiation and then the system determines the presence of metal based on the length of time the back EMF takes to return to ground .

Comment: Do you want to boost power and suppress which harmonics and how much?

Comment: So, in my new circuit, the transmit circuitry is the same except I'm using a microcontroller that is producing a PWM with a frequency of 5KHz and a duty cycle of 25% .I want as much power as possible to be transmitted from the antenna during the "on" cycle, i.e. the 25% Which harmonics to be suppressed I'm not sure. I'm reading the signal in from an ADC at 1Msps, so harmonics less than half of that to prevent aliasing?  If I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: More power with more duty cycle , but better  with tuned high ripple current cap near 2.3uF (  MOV type cap) and choke estimated at 220uH with harmonic shunt tuned see here my sim. http://tinyurl.com/yyxs9hwp and change FET to <100 mOhm approx instead of 1.5R

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand that if I increased the duty cycle the coil would have more time to accumulate energy but I'm trying to get as efficient a power transfer within the allotted time frame as possible. I could also increase the voltage to get higher power, but I want to stick within the power limits of the original design but make it more efficient. I need time to digest your simulation, I've got very little experience with this, but it looks like a redesign of the transmit circuit, with a series resonant circuit on the high side?

Comment: Did you press the switch ?

Comment: Hi Tony, I did press the switch with the simulation running to connect the FET to the clock source. Is the 220uH inductor to ground a representation of what the transmitter coil would be in my circuit? I was expecting to see a 12V square wave across an inductor but I'm struggling to interpret the circuit.

Comment: Ask a better question